# Retrieve indexes of min and max values in np.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, gis

i am working on some tif files and i have to plot dependecies between temperature and vegatation index based on .tif file. It was just FYI. Now my programming problem. 
I'm using python 2.7 (x64). 
I have big ndarray form NumPy lib, contains values of temerature and second (same size) with vegetation idex. `mergedmask` is my mask (same size like other arrays) where False value mean it is valid data.

```
 maxTS = np.amax(toa[mergedmask==False])
 minTS = np.amin(toa[mergedmask==False])
 maxVI = np.amax(ndvi1[mergedmask==False])
 minVi = np.amin(ndvi1[mergedmask==False])
```

In upper variables i have minimum and maximum values of `TS` (temperature) and `VI` (vegetation index). Everything is ok. I am happy. Now i have to find coords in `toa` and `ndvi1` arrays. So i am using this:

```
ax,ay = np.unravel_index(ndvi1[mergedmask==False].argmin(),ndvi1.shape)
```

To simplify my msg i just focus only on `minVI`. Upper line return 2 indexes. Then:

```
newMinVi = ndvi1[ax][ay]
```

should assign to `newMinVi` same value as `minVi`. But it doesn't. I check near indexes like `ax-1, ax+1, ay-1,ay+1` and all of them is not even close to my `minVi` value. Have you any ideas to get coord of my minVi value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ndvi1[mergedmask==False].argmin()` will give you the index of the minimum in `ndvi1[mergedmask==False]`, i.e., the index into a new array, corresponding to the places where `mergedmask` is `False`.

The problem here is that `ndvi1[mergedmask==False]` isn't really a *mask*. It selects those values of `ndvi1` which meets the condition, and assembles those values into a new 1D array. For instance, check what `ndvi1[mergedmask==False].size` is, and compare it to `ndvi1.size`.

What you probably want to be doing is to create a real masked array:

```
ndvi1_masked = np.ma.masked_array(ndvi1, (mergedmask==False))
ax, ay = np.unravel_index(ndvi1_masked.argmin(), ndvi1.shape)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Almost what i want.

```
ndvi1_masked = np.ma.masked_array(ndvi1, (mergedmask==False))
```

Masked pretty well but not this values what i want. I just have to change statement to `mergedmask==False` and finally i got:

```
myNdviMasked = np.ma.masked_array(ndvi1,(mergedmask!=False))
bx, by = np.unravel_index(myNdviMasked.argmin(), myNdviMasked.shape)
```

Thank You for help  :)